# this form return 404 error in laravel blade.php

Tags: laravel, custom-error-pages

this is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="{{url('/contacts')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my web route

```
Route::post('/contacts', [AdminController::class, 'contacts']);
```

and this is my base url in .env

```
APP_URL=http://localhost/addressbook/public
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to work with urls to routes in `Laravel` is using named routes. Add the name call to your route definition.

```
Route::post('/contacts', [AdminController::class, 'contacts'])->name('contacts.store');
```

Now you can get the url to the route like this.

```
<form action="{{ route('contacts.store') }}" method="post">
```

If you need variables to the route call, it is done like this based on the url parameter naming.

```
route('contacts.store', ['contact' => $contact]);
```

Your app url looks wrong, at least i would not expect it to have public in the url. Either change your `.htaccess` or have a different local setup. For what it is worth, `php artisan serve` can serve the files locally and just needs a `SQL` database, for a simple development environment.

```
APP_URL=http://localhost/addressbook
```

Comment: I use xampp. Btw I always code with this style and It worked well but It doesn't now

Comment: thank u mister but I found. It was because of index.php in the route.  I needed to write in my base url

Comment: It's not intended to have `/public` or `index.php` in your URL, mrhn is correct when he says that you should work on that.